# Why can't I declare a variable or function more than once with different types?

Tags: forward-declaration, multiple-definition-error, using-declaration

Okay I know "One Definition Rule", but when I try to declare a variable with different types subsequently in source code, I run into some mistake like following:

```
int fkc();
void fkc();
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MEnUb.png)

I mean these two statements are just two declarations, not definitions. Alright, Does every declaration have to have only one unique definition?

Comment: 1. Those are function declarations 2. What is unclear here? How should the compiler figure out which of the 2 you want to refer to?

Answer (score 0):

Because you cannot overload the method just by changing return type . It is not allowed. The compiler distinguishes function invocations based on signature.and the signature of function includes only function name and arugments like

`func(int x....)` which does not include return type

Answer (score 0):

In C++, you can't overload functions based on return type.

Overload resolution takes into account the function name , cv-qualifiers , the number of parameters and their types.

You could do something like:

```
auto fck()
{
    if constexpr(...) return my_int;
    else /* do smth without return */
}
```

but that's not function overloading of course.